# I have installed SAP crystal report but it's not visible in my visual studio 2017 tab

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

I have installed SAP crystal report but it's not visible in my visual studio 2017 tab. How can i make visible for asp.net?

[image: Screen]

Comment: did you check in web?

Comment: Did you install a stand-alone version of CR or the CR for Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: no from where i can get  ? i just download SAP reports and install it but nothing appears in VS

Comment: [Start at this link](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/install-crystal-reports-visual-studio/).  It has links to the downloads and instructions to get you started.  If you get stuck, update the question here with more specific issues that you are having.

Comment: i installed it again but didn't get anything there.